# An elementary question about images of relations.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi everyone I'd like to know if the next proofs are correct or maybe needs some adjustments.

Let $\,R\,$ be a binary relation, and $A \text{ and } B\,$ be sets. Prove:

(1) $\,R[\,A \cup B\,] = R[\,A\,] \cup R[\,B\,] $

($\Rightarrow$)

$\,y\in R[\,A \cup B\,] \leftrightarrow \exists x\in A\cup B. \, \langle x,y\rangle \in R \rightarrow \langle x,y\rangle \in R \text {  ( for some } x\in A\cup B ).$

For $\,x\in A,\,\, y\in R[\,A\,] \rightarrow y \in R[\,A\,] \cup R[\,B\,].\,$ A symmetrical argument can be used, if $ \,x\in B,\,\,  y\in R[\,B\,]\,\rightarrow \,y \in R[\,A\,] \cup R[\,B\,].\,$  Then, in either case $y \in R[\,A\,] \cup R[\,B\,].\,$

($\Leftarrow$)

$y \in  R[\,A\,] \cup R[\,B\,] \leftrightarrow y\in R[\,A\,] \vee y\in R[\,B\,] \leftrightarrow \exists x\in A. \, \langle x,y\rangle \in R \vee \exists x'\in B.\,\langle x',y\rangle $

If $\, \langle x,y\rangle \in R\,$  for some $ x \in A.\, $ So, $x \in A\cup B \wedge \langle x,y\rangle \in R \rightarrow  y\in R[\,A \cup B\,].\,  $ Symetrically, $\langle x',y\rangle \in R\,$ for some $ x' \in B,\,x' \in A\cup B \wedge \langle x',y\rangle \in R\, \rightarrow y\in R[\,A \cup B\,].\,  $  Therefore, in either case $\,y\in R[\,A \cup B\,].\,  $

(2) $\,R[\,A \cap B\,] \subseteq R[\,A\,] \cap R[\,B\,] $

$y \in R[\,A \cap B\,] \leftrightarrow \exists x\in A\cap B.\, \langle x,y\rangle \in R \rightarrow \langle x,y\rangle \in R  \text{ ( for some } x\in A\cap B\,).  $

$x\in A\cap B \rightarrow x\in A \wedge \langle x,y\rangle \in R  \rightarrow y\in R[\,A\,].\, $ Using a symmetric argument, $y\in R[\,B\,]$  ( $x\in A\cap B \rightarrow x\in B \wedge \langle x,y\rangle \in R  \rightarrow y\in R[\,B\,]).\, $ Then, $y \in R[\,A\,] \cap  R[\,B\,].\,$

(3) $\,R[\,A - B\,] \supseteq R[\,A\,] - R[\,B\,] $

$y\in R[\,A\,] - R[\,B\,] \leftrightarrow y \in R[\,A\,] \wedge y\notin R[\,B\,] \leftrightarrow  \exists x\in A. \, \langle x,y\rangle \in R  \wedge \neg \exists x'\in B. \, \langle x',y\rangle \in R \leftrightarrow  \exists x\in A. \, \langle x,y\rangle \in R  \wedge \forall x'\in B. \, \langle x',y\rangle \notin R \rightarrow \langle x,y\rangle \in R \text {  ( for some } x\in A ). $

We need to show that  $ x\notin B.\,$ By the sake of contradiction assume  $ x\in B,\,$ then $\langle x,y\rangle \notin R,$  a contradiction. Therefore $ x\in A \wedge x\notin B,\, x\in A-B \wedge\langle x,y\rangle \in R,, $ then $\,y\in R[\,A - B\,].\,$

Do you think my attempt is correct? I know, I should be use more words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are correct, but they would be **much** easier to read if you’d use more words. For the first one, for instance:

> Suppose first that $y\in R[A\cup B]$. Then there is an $x\in A\cup B$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$. If $x\in A$, then $y\in R[A]\subseteq R[A]\cup R[B]$, and if $x\notin A$, then $x\in B$, so $y\in R[B]\subseteq R[A]\cup R[B]$, so $R[A\cup B]\subseteq R[A]\cup R[B]$.
>
> Now suppose that $y\in R[A]\cup R[B]$. Then either there is an $x\in A$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$, or there is an $x\in B$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$. In either case $x\in A\cup B$, so there is an $x\in A\cup B$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$, and therefore $\langle x,y\rangle\in R[A\cup B]$. It follows that $R[A]\cup R[B]\subseteq R[A\cup B]$ and hence that $R[A\cup B]=R[A]\cup R[B]$.

Comment: As usual thank you so much. I'll try to use more words and less symbols. :)

Comment: I know that if I want to show the converse of (2) and (3) doesn't hold, it sufficient a counterexample. But, if  I'd like to go further, I mean, if I want to show under what circumstances the converse holds. I worked with the exercise as usual and I found, for example in (2) that the relation must be "injective": For $y \in R[\,A\,] \cap R[\,B\,]$. Then there is a $x \in A$ such that $\langle  x,y \rangle \in R$ and a $x' \in B$ s.t. $\langle  x',y \rangle \in R.$ So, only we need a $x =x'$ to show that $x\in A\cap B.$ However I have a problem with (3). Could you give some hint, please? Thanks

Comment: @Jose: You’re welcome. (3) is true for all sets $A$ and $B$ iff $x\mathbin{R}y$ and $x'\mathbin{R}y$ imply that $x=x'$, i.e., iff $|R^{-1}[\{y\}]|\le 1$ for all $y$. It’s easy to check that this implies (3). And if this is false, let $x$ and $x'$ be distinct elements such that $x\mathbin{R}y$ and $x'\mathbin{R}y$, and let $A=\{x\}$ and $B=\{x'\}$. Clearly $R[A\setminus B]=\{y\}\ne\varnothing=R[A]\setminus R[B]$.

Comment: Suppose $y\in R$, and $x\,R\,y$ and $x'\,R\,y$ implies $x=x'$. Then there is an $x\in A-B$ such that $x\,R\,y$. Let $x'\in B$ be arbitrary. By contraposition $\langle x',y \rangle \notin R$ since $x\not= x'$ and $x\,R\,y$. Thus for each $x'\in B,\,\langle x',y \rangle \notin R$. Then $y \in R[\,A\,]$ and we need to seek that $y\notin R[\,B\,]$. Suppose $y\in R[\,B\,]$ then there is an $x'\in B$ such that $\langle x',y \rangle \in R$, a contradiction. Then $y\notin R[\,B\,]$. It follows that $y \in R[\,A\,]$ and $y \notin R[\,B\,]$, i.e., $y \in R[\,A\,]-R[\,B\,]$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Jose: You're welcome.